# How well is UTF-8 supported in email?

Tags: email, utf-8

How well is UTF-8 supported in various email clients?

I know it was somewhat of a problem five or so years ago -- but is it still something we should worry over?

I am wondering if I should re-encode strings to some other encoding before sending. For example, Russian text would be stored as UTF-8 but when sending email notifications, I could just re-encode it on-the-fly as ISO-8859-5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a [comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients#Features) of just about every email client and whether it supports UTF-8

Plus, wikipedia says:

> The Internet Mail Consortium (IMC)
>   recommends that all email programs be
>   able to display and create mail using
>   UTF-8.

But you can also send an email in multiple formats, if you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the comparison does not include old versions.

Answer (score 3):

The only place I've found where UTF-8 can be problematic is Japan, where at least a couple of years ago many web mail services and older mobile devices still couldn't cope with it smoothly. It's a bit sad, particularly as the native multibyte encodings (Shift-JIS, ISO-2022-JP etc.) are uniformly awful.

Other East Asian countries with multibyte character sets may also be affected.

Answer (score 0):

today when re-encoding russian UTF-8 text as ISO-8859-5 it is risk to garble new UTF-8 russian ruble currency character U+20BD RUBLE SIGN. It's the same problem with euro currency character support in ISO-8859-1 (Latin1) which is no support I mean.
I've found these articles very helpful about international characters support in email
http://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/management/international-characters-in-mailchimp
https://wordtothewise.com/2010/03/which-is-better-utf-8-or-iso/

Here is a C# code example for problem with codepage ISO-8859-5 and russian ruble currency character:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string russian_text = "Русский текст co знаком валюты рубля ₽";

        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.WriteLine(russian_text);

        var encoded_bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-5"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(russian_text));

        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-5");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-5").GetString(encoded_bytes));
    }
}
```

}